# Javascript Promises Unexpected Execution Flow

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

**Overview**

I have a html page with a span. The inner text says "Initial State". The script block loads once the body has been rendered and there is a call to a personService to UpdatePerson passing in a Person object. The UpdatePerson method sleeps for 5 seconds to mimic a service call that takes some time and then returns a Promise with a "random" true or false result. The main code block then based on true or false will set the message in the span inner text to "Success" or "Failed". After the promise I set the inner text to "Awaiting result...."

**Expected Order of Text in Span**
 1) Initial State
 2) Awaiting results....
 3) (5 seconds later) .... Success or Failed

**Actual Results**
1) Initial State
5 seconds later ...
2) Awaiting results....
3) Success or Failed

I thought that once the script execution hit the line which consumes the Promise that execution would continue immediately to the next line which sets the inner text to "Awaiting result..." and then when the Promise state changed from Pending (ie 5 seconds later) it would then switch into the execution of resolve or reject. The promise seemed to execute synchronously instead of asynchronously.

I'm missing something here either in my understanding or how I have gone about mimicking a delay in a call to another task, ie updating the person. Can someone clear up my confusion?

Script starts via the onload attribute of the body tag calling **StartExample()**

```
  function Sleep(milliseconds) {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
          break;
        }
      }
    }

  function Person(name, age, gender)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
  }

  personService = {}

  personService.UpdatePerson = function(person){
    Sleep(5000);
    return Promise.resolve((Math.random() >= 0.5));
  };

  function StartExample(){

        var resolve = function(){
              // get resultSpan from DOM, write "Success" message
        }

        var reject = function(){
             // get resultSpan from DOM, write "Failed" message
        }

        var p = new Person("tom", 15, "m");            

        personService.UpdatePerson(p)
        .then(function(result){
            if(result){resolve();}
            else{reject();}
        })
        .catch(error => { alert(error);})

        var resultSpan = document.getElementById("resultSpan"); 
        resultSpan.innerText = "Awaiting result...";       
  }
</script>

 <span id="resultSpan"  style="background-color: blue;">Initial State</span>
```

Comment: You should not do sleep like that in javascript... What you wrote will block the main thread as it is synchronous, so it will wait till the sleep function is done.

Comment: `Sleep(5000);` blocks the browser from doing anything else for 5 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't how you mimic a delay in javascript. Instead use `window.setTimeout()` like this:

```
  personService.UpdatePerson = function(person){
      return new Promise( function( resolve ) {
          window.setTimeout( function() { 
              resolve(Math.random() >= 0.5), 
          5000 );
      });
  };
```

What you're doing is blocking, which is pretty much always bad in javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was doing something daft somewhere